# How to restore the access to the Samsung BIOS after restoring the MBR with the Dual-boot Repair tool on Windows 10?

Tags: boot, bios, windows-10, grub

I have a Samsung Ativ Book 2, which came with Windows 8.1 as I bought, but I updated to Windows 10. I needed to make a dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 because of my work, but I didn't wanted to risk it, so I tried to install Ubuntu to a pendrive. I've even put the bootloader for this installation on this pendrive. But whenever I tried to boot with it, it showed the grub command line (the one with the most basic linux terminal commands) and couldn't boot to Ubuntu from the external drive, and I had to type `exit` to enter Windows. So I took the courage to make a proper dual-boot, and used the [Dual-boot Repair Tool](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) to restore my MBR. I just clicked **Automatic Repair** and BAM, my Windows was booting normally, without the grub command line.
But then, when I tried to start the installation, I couldn't access the BIOS anymore, no keys brought the Samsung menu. I tried the SYS and the ALL, with and without the `/force` option, of the bootsect command line options:

```
bootsect.exe {/help | /nt52 | /nt60} {SYS | ALL | <drive_letter:>} [/force]
```

And even tried this:

```
bcdedit /set {default} path \windows\system32\winload.efi
```

Nothing worked... I need to access the BIOS. What can I do?

Comment: samsung site flash bios?

Comment: I can't seem to find this for np270e5j-xd2br

Comment: Call samsung. If they can do anything or can't do anything much they can at least point you to the driver and other things download page for your laptop on the support section of their website!